# Win32 cannot get the window to be repainted and updated

Tags: winapi

In a Win32 application, I am trying to set the background color after the window has been created. It doesn't matter that it will change it for all instances of the window.

```cpp
HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255));
SetClassLongPtr(handle, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG_PTR)brush);
RedrawWindow(handle, nullptr, nullptr, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
UpdateWindow(handle);
```

Apparently, either of the last 2 lines should force the update. However, the background is updated only after the window is resized.

Comment: What if you set RDW_ERASE too? Afaik in your case on WM_PAINT is executed.

Comment: Why don't you change the code of the effected window. Doing it in this way is very strange and might affect all other windows using this class...

Comment: Yes, it does work when RDW_ERASE is specified. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `SetClassLongPtr()` returns the previous value being replaced. So, if you had a previous `HBRUSH` assigned, this will return that old brush. Make sure you are freeing it when you are done using it.

Comment: Bravo for the -1 ers.

In the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-redrawwindow
, the following is stated:
* RDW_ERASE: Causes the window to receive a WM_ERASEBKGND message when the window is repainted.
* RDW_UPDATENOW: Causes the affected windows (...) to receive WM_NCPAINT, WM_ERASEBKGND, and WM_PAINT messages, if necessary, before the function returns.

Therefore, it claims RDW_UPDATENOW includes the WM_ERASEBKGND message. However, it only works when RDW_ERASE is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RedrawWindow` with `RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW` only regenerates a WM_PAINT message.

In most windoiws the background is drawn in `WM_ERASEBGGND` so use the flag `RDW_ERASE`.

Also free the old class brush that you just overwrote. Otherwise executing your code often will cause a memory leak. Also remember that this code will affect all windoes of this class. Not only one.

The normal way to change the background color of a window is to overwrite (subclass) `WM_ERASEBKGND` and set the required color here.

Comment: Note that the effects of default process for the [`WM_ERASEBKGND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-erasebkgnd) are documented: *"The `DefWindowProc` function erases the background by using the class background brush specified by the `hbrBackground` member of the `WNDCLASS` structure."*